# editing row doubles rows in c#

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to let a user edit the products but after I finished the code. 
it accualty editing but its setting all the rows with the same selected value

this is the code I have wrote

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET Item_Name=@Item_Name, Item_Price=@Item_Price, Item_Code=@Item_Code, Item_Stock=@Item_Stock, Item_ExpDate=@Item_ExpDate", con);

SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[5];

param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Item_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
param[0].Value = namesearch.Text;

param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Item_Price", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
param[1].Value = pricesearch.Text;

param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Item_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35);
param[2].Value = codesearch.Text;

param[3] = new SqlParameter("@Item_Stock", SqlDbType.Int);
param[3].Value = Convert.ToInt32(stocksearch.Text);

param[4] = new SqlParameter("@Item_ExpDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
param[4].Value = expdatesearch.Text;

con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Products", con);
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

con.Close();
```

Comment: That because in your Update query you are not specifying a given row, so it is updating all rows to the values you are passing it. Your Update query needs some kind of where clause.

Comment: You forget WHERE in your UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SQL statement to:
`"UPDATE Products SET Item_Name=@Item_Name, Item_Price=@Item_Price, Item_Stock=@Item_Stock, Item_ExpDate=@Item_ExpDate WHERE Item_Code=@Item_Code"`, assuming `'Item_Code'` is your unique identifier. The `WHERE` clause in SQL is used to filter the number of rows being effected by the `UPDATE`, so if it is left out it will update all rows in the table.

Comment: Thank you I understanded what is happening :P I was stupid for this.